# Clustered leaflet markers with sum (not count) totals: how to get consistent round red shape and label format like in unclustered markers

Tags: javascript, css, r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I would like to modify the behavior of leaflet grouping feature to total on grouping and preserve a round red bubble shape dependent on value.

My data contains columns:

lon lat sales_ytd

I would like to cluster data depending on zoom using **clusterOption**s = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(sum.formula))

Here is my function. I do not know JS but I tried numerous examples and the function works by summing up the grouped values.

```
 sum.formula  = JS("function (cluster) {    
        var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
        var sum = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          sum += Number(markers[i].options.mag);
    //      sum += 1;
        }
          var size = sum/30000;

        return new L.DivIcon({ html:  sum ,  iconSize: L.point(size, size)});
      }")
```

Evidently L.DivIcon() returns a square... **is there a way for it to return round red bubble?**

Then I am trying using it in a shiny app (R code).

```
renderLeaflet({
  leaflet(df_summary_towns()) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    radius = ~sales_ytd/30000,
    color = 'red',
    stroke = FALSE, 
    fillOpacity = 0.5,
    options = markerOptions(mag = ~ sales_ytd),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(sum.formula))
  ) %>% 
    addLabelOnlyMarkers(
      ~lon, ~lat, 
      options = markerOptions(mag = ~ sales_ytd),
      label =  ~scales::number(sales_ytd),
      labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, direction = 'center', textOnly = T),
      clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(sum.formula)))
})
```

[image: Grouped markers]

The grouping somewhat works, the values are totaled for clustered data and if I click them, leaflet zooms and show individual points (nice red circles with values inside). But the grouped markers are white squares and not round red circles like the individual points. Also I do not know how to achieve consistent formatting for numbers. In R it is easy but the definition of grouped markers is now in JS.
How can it be achieved: ***consistent shape, color and size dependent on value in both ungrouped and grouped markers and consistent number formats***? 
One can also see **I tried normalizing the size in R, and I divided size/1000 in JS - I did not know how to pass the sum of the data.frame column to JS**.

Comment: Fixing the style can be done with CSS (I can post later if useful), but I don't really understand how you want to define for the radius for the clustered markers. Your formula for single markers is essentially 1 for the marker with the highest sales and 0 for the marker with the lowest sale, but how do you want to translate that when grouping markers? I.e. if you group a 0.8, 0.7 and 0.2 marker what should the value of the radius be?

Comment: @NicE Do you have any ideas how to tweak CSS to get the grouped markers round  and semitransparent? And how to tweak CSS to get the markers labels number format roudned and with space separating thousands like in ungrouped markers? I will also accept your suggestion how to controll size for both grouped and ungrouped.
You hinted it can be done with CSS. If you can suggest the solution I will be happy to grant you  100 rep points bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try tweaking the custom `sum.formula` function to add a CSS class to the marker that you can then customise, as well as format the number to add thousand separators.

I have added a MWE example below, I have added the `custom-cluster-icon` class to the icons, and formatted the numbers using the regexp in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).

The CSS included in the header of the shiny page, as well as added in line in the `sum.formula` output helps center the labels, and add the red marker circles.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

#dummy data for example
df_summary_towns=quakes
df_summary_towns$sales_ytd=sample(2000:5000,1000)

sum.formula  = JS("function (cluster) {    
    var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    var sum = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(markers[i].options.mag);
    }
      var size = sum/10000;
      var formatted_number = Math.round(sum).toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ' ');

    return new L.DivIcon({ className: 'custom-cluster-icon', html: '<div style=\"line-height:'+size+'px; white-space: nowrap;\">'+formatted_number+'</div>'   , iconSize: L.point(size, size) });
  }")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .custom-cluster-icon {
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      "))
  ),
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df_summary_towns) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        radius = ~sales_ytd/10000,
        color = 'red',
        stroke = FALSE, 
        fillOpacity = 0.5,
        options = markerOptions(mag = ~ sales_ytd, min_sales =  ~min(sales_ytd), max_sales = ~ max(sales_ytd)),
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(sum.formula))
      ) %>% 
      addLabelOnlyMarkers(
        ~long, ~lat, 
        options = markerOptions(mag = ~ sales_ytd),
        label =  ~scales::number(sales_ytd),
        labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, direction = 'center', textOnly = T),
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(sum.formula)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It works like a charm. What do you recommend to study to know this? I only know R (well... writing basic functions) and VBA... is it just JS programming or a specific sub-dialect? I am very grateful and impressed.

Comment: @NicE How can the output be saved as a html file?

Answer (score 2):

For total number of markers/layers you can use the getLayers() function which will return an array of all the component layers of that cluster.

```
var testCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
L.marker([event.latlng.lat, 
event.latlng.lng]).addTo(testCluster);
testCluster.getLayers();
```

It will return array of each marker as layer.

Alternatively You can use this:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.getChildCount){     
            console.log(layer._childClusters.length)        
            console.log(layer._childCount);  
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks... however it seems I need somehow to customise markers to be round, transparent and red. And I need to customise number formats of clustered points. I know what css is and how to find help on that... I seem not to have any clue how to inject it here in JS.

Comment: @Pedro_JR Do you have any ideas how to tweak CSS to get the grouped markers round and semitransparent? And how to tweak CSS to get the markers labels number format roudned and with space separating thousands like in ungrouped markers? I will also accept your suggestion how to controll size for both grouped and ungrouped. You hinted it can be done with CSS. If you can suggest the solution I will be happy to grant you 100 rep points bounty.

Comment: I'd love to but am not really an expert in this field, I would have tried cloning your project and solving it, but am currently busy with a project