# Show the aggregate value on markerClusterOptions in R

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, markerclusterer

I want to do a map in R, that will show the points in clusters when you zoom in/zoom out and in the same time show a aggregate value.
Now I have this code:

```
m <- leaflet(acdt_1, width = "200%", height = "800px") %>%
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

This gives me a map with all the points, grouped in clusters and it shows the no of points in every cluster when zoom in/zoom out.
[image]

Instead of the no of points in every cluster, I want a value (sum of a specific value for every points).

Any idea?

Thank you,

Comment: Some discussion here may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226819/clustered-leaflet-markers-with-sum-not-count-totals-how-to-get-consistent-rou